# Is it possible to show two alignments in textview using iphone sdk?

Tags: ios4, uiwebview, uitextview, arabic, text-alignment

In my app i need to show Arabic text and English text in a textview. The Arabic text should be right aligned the English text should be left aligned.

Is it possible with a textview? I have tried using a webview instead of a textview, and I am getting what I need. But scrolling the webview is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same name for the property, `selectionString` instead of `selctionString`.

Or you need to declare the property name and make it synthesize:

```
@synthesize selctionString = selectionString; // Missing "e"
```

Comment: Since the OP didn't include code, how do you know there is a typo?

Comment: yes you are correct observe the date clearly
it shows 1-11-11- 11'o clock got it how it is possible